# Understanding when to use CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is just a general question regarding the concept of CTE. I learnt how to make them but I am still unclear about "WHERE" to use them.

Could anyone summarize to me of where I should be using them?

Thanks

Comment: ....where it makes your query easier to understand.

Comment: When you need recursion, or need a sub-query - these are 2 very distinct types of cte.

Comment: @Dal K, so if I have 5 tables each presenting a different set of information but common to 2 tables, I can use it?

Comment: @AttitudeBlack I have no idea without a [mre] but its a tool, so you use it when you need to use it.

Comment: A CTE lets you name a common query.  Much like a function does to let you encapsulate, reuse, document, break down, and avoid repeating things.

Comment: @shawnt00 except unlike a function you can only use a cte once... its just a glorified sub-query (aside from recursion).

Comment: @DaleK How is that true? You can define other ctes in terms of it. You can join two instances together... It's obviously not a perfect parallel but there are definitely some common benefits.

Comment: @shawnt00 yip, but in the end you can use the data exactly once (you can do it all using sub-queries if desired, its just using CTEs is probably a bit clearer).

Comment: If you mean by defining cte parameters then perhaps that's fair. `with cte as (select ... from ...), t1 as (select * from cte where X = @A), t2 as (select * from cte where X = @B) ...`. You can't parameterize directly but you can still go a long way toward that end. And what would prevent the next version of the standard from defining just such a thing?

Comment: @shawnt00 sorry you've lost me. Not sure where parameters come into it.

Comment: @DaleK They don't but they certainly could. Maybe take a look at C preprocessor macros. I would never say something like "call the CTE" and belabor the concept, yet it would also be silly to claim that functions are just "glorified GOTOs" and ignore what they buy you.

Comment: @shwant00, wait hold on! Couldn't we do that in a single expression using AND rather than making more cte?

Comment: Give me all pairs of triangles and rectangles: `with Shapes as (select <complicated query that I don't want to repeat>), Triangles as (select * from Shapes where type = 'T'), Rectangles as (select * from Shapes where type = 'R') select t.ID, r.ID from Triangles t cross join Rectangles r` Not a common thing you'll want to do per se but you've just broken down the logic into something that makes sense at a high level.

Comment: `with Func as (select result from <repeatable query>) select * from my data t cross apply (select result from Func f where f.Id = t.myParameter) as Lookup`

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 main cases to use Common Table Expressions:

- when you have to (hierarchical query / recursion);
- to make the query easier to understand;
- to show off to colleagues.

Comment: Thank-you. I think, I am looking for a hierarchial structure because that is the flow of tables that I am working with.

Comment: @AttitudeBlack I would encourage you to either modify this question or ask a new one that describe your **specific** current problem "1. I have table a that looks like [this] and table B that looks like [this]. 2. The expected result is [result here]. 3. I've tried [...] / I don't know how to approach this"

Comment: Microsoft has a help page dedicated to CTEs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 - which is more about *how* (with examples) rather than *when* but it may be helpful.

Comment: Thank-you. Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 2):

There are two times you **MUST** use a CTE:

- To implement a recursive query.  No other way to do it.
- To use the same subquery multiple times in your query.  For example, let's say you wanted to look for bank accounts doing large internal transfers.  You could summarize inflows and outflows by account by day and then join the result to itself (inflow total to outflow total) to come up with the candidates.  In the old (pre-CTE) days, you would have to repeat the summarization query twice and hope the optimizer would see they were identical.  Now, summarize them in a CTE and then reference the intermediate results twice; the optimizer nails it every time.

Beyond that, it's purely a matter of taste.  Personally, I only use a CTE for these two scenarios.